# How to write a simple unit test for GraphQL Subscription over websocket?

Tags: java, junit, graphql, graphql-java, graphql-subscriptions

My backend is a webflux server using the `graphql-java-kickstart` (v11.0.0) library and I have a bunch of graphql http requests right now.

I'm using Spring's `WebTestClient` to test my graphql Queries and Mutations.
Basically, I'll just call it and compare the response like so

```
webTestClient
  .post()
  .uri("/graphql")
  .header(...)
  .body(Mono.just(request), JsonNode.class)
  .exchange()
  .expectStatus()
  .isOk()
  .expectBody(JsonNode.class)
  .returnResult()
  .getResponseBody()
```

But this is over a normal HTTP and simple REST protocol.

With GraphQL Subscriptions, I need to set up a websocket and do the Apollo (subscription-transport.ws) handshake protocol before sending the Subscription request in, and I have to wait for a response async.

I have manually verified the subscription works with the WebSocket Test Client chrome extension

What's the correct way to write a unit test for this?

Suppose I have a simple Subscription that just returns the timestamp back every second

```
type Subscription {
  clock: String!
}
```

How do I write a unit test for this? What library or client should I use?
A link or example would be awesome!